# Which HTML is the best long text format?

Tags: html

The main two formats of writing too long text are:

```
    <p>
    test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test </p>


    <p>
    test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test </p>
```

and

```
     <p>
        test test test test test test test test test test 
    test test test test test test test test test test test 
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test <br /> <br />

test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
</p>
```

Which one is the best for search engines, structure ... etc?

Comment: First you have to understand the concept of a "paragraph" (which is what `<p>` stands for).

Comment: @BoltClock so the first method?

Comment: Basically, yes. If you're writing text that ends up flowing into two paragraphs, use two `<p>` elements.

Comment: Why is my comment flagged as not helpful? How else does one decide if one should use `<p>` elements unless they understand the purpose of the text being written? Should I be posting it as an answer instead?

Comment: I can't think of any circumstance when a double line break would be appropriate markup (every situation I can think of that might use them is better served by margins, paddings, paragraphs or pre-formatted text).

Comment: @BoltClock you didn't answer the question because of that is flagged, if you have an answer to my "Which one is the best for search engines, structure ... etc?" please post it and i will accept it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Jimmy: If you want me to post an answer, you can tell me directly in the comments. Don't use a comment flag - that's not what it's for, especially not a comment flag that says "not helpful", which is confusing to a moderator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference at all.

Most search engines only give more value to text in some tags that represent the overall content. For example what's inside H1 tag may indicate what the content in the page is about.

Separating long text with `<br />` or new paragraph won't affect the search engine results.

I will add that using the `<p>` tag to separate paragraphs make more sense in the eye of the programmer.

Comment: You realize that it's against the rules to solicit votes and accepts like this? (I don't actually care that my answer was unaccepted - in fact I'm deleting it since the OP doesn't seem to appreciate it enough to keep it accepted and I'm not exactly proud of it anyway, but this doesn't change the fact that such behavior is inappropriate.)